# Search text and image OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: java, android

i implemented a search text for my list,

Every list row item includes a text and image that i downloaded from server.

i alsways keeps two list, one is the original List of text and images and other one is the sorted Lists of text and image...

if my list containes only 4 items, so my app works well, however if my list containes 20 items and every image is 1MB and i need to keep two lists listImagesOriginal , image_array inside adapter  ( = 40MB)  i recieve a OutOfMemory Exception.

how can i reduce the memory consuption that i will not recive a OutOfMemory Exception?

thanks alot

how can i reduce the

```
private MyCustomAdapter adapter;

private List<String> text = new ArrayList<String>();
private List<Bitmap> listImages;



private List<String> textOriginal = new ArrayList<String>();
private List<Bitmap> listImagesOriginal =new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

adapter =new MyCustomAdapter(text,listImages);
         ListView.setAdapter(adapter);



searchText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.profile_page_search);

         searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
         {
             public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
             {
                   // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
                 textlength = searchText.getText().length();
                 adapter.deleteAllForSearch();
                 for (int i = 0; i < textOriginal.size(); i++)
                 {

                         if(textOriginal.get(i).contains(
                                 searchText.getText().toString().trim()))
                         {
                             adapter.addObjectForSearch(textOriginal.get(i), listImagesOriginal.get(i));
                         }

                 }
             }
             public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,
                     int start, int count, int after)
             {
                 // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
             }
             public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,
                     int start, int before, int count)
             {

              }
          });




class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
          public   List<String> text_array = new ArrayList<String>();
          public   List<Bitmap> image_array = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();


          public int getCount(){
               return text_array.size();
          }

          MyCustomAdapter(List<String> text, List<Bitmap>)
          {

           text_array = text;
           image_array = image;

          }

          public long getItemId(int position){
               return position;
          }
          public String getItem(int position){
               return null;
          }
          public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
               //my implementation
          }

public void addObjectForSearch(String text, Bitmap bitmap) {
                text_array.add(text);
                image_array.add(bitmap);


                notifyDataSetChanged();

          }
```

Comment: Keeping images loaded on memory isn't a good idea as it consumes memory enormously. (Especially for apps, which might slow down the device and consume lots of power) Unless you have a particular reason to keep images loaded, try storing the image somewhere locally and have its file path on memory instead.

Comment: thanks, how can i save images to sdCard? and in the exit from my app to delete them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

40MB is way too much for android.  Every phone has a per app memory limit, 40MB is higher than even most high end phones use.  You need to implement disk and/or memory caching of your images.

Comment: thanks, how can i save images to sdCard? and in the exit from my app to delete them?

Comment: To save ot the SD card, you need the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissing.  Then you can call getExternalStorageDirectory to get the location of the external drive.  Then write to files there as normal.

Comment: thanks, also, the android emulator will support write images to sd?

Comment: Yes the emulator can support sd's functionality, it can save the contents between sessions.

https://github.com/ZaBlanc/WebImageView

I what I use to handle memory/disk caching of images.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a cache and/or store them into persistent memory (DB, filesystem, etc), as you don't want all those bitmaps loaded into memory at the same time, especially if you don't see them all at the same time. Many older devices have VM heap sizes around `16-24MB`, and you need to be able to stay within a reasonable amount of memory usage.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html